# QGIS Set Composer Legend to shrink the font size to fit

Tags: qgis, legend, qgis-2.10

QGIS 2.10.1. I have read that it is "impossible to make the legend smaller then its contents".

Is there a way to set the legend to shrink the font size when re-sizing the bounding box? Or when you add a new item to the legend? From my reading of answers to related questions I suspect not. (I am not a Python coder.)